# Can't we use strtok on different strings in a single program?

Tags: c, string

I was trying to write a  calculator program and so part of this I need to evaluate an expression.

So I need to perform the operation based on the operator given. I am taking the whole expression into a string.

For example it might be 5+6 or 5*6.

So I have written it in this way:

```
    char input1[20] = "";
    char input2[20] = "";
    char output[20] = "";
    char *arg1= NULL, *arg2 = NULL;
    int value;

    getinput ( input1); //Function for getting the expression
    strcpy (input2, input1);

    if ( arg1 = strtok (input1, "*"))
    {
        arg2 = strtok (NULL, "");
        value = atoi(arg1) * atoi(arg2);
    }
    else
    {
        char* arg1, *arg2;

        arg1 = strtok ( input2, "+");
        arg2 = strtok ( NULL, "");

        value = atoi (arg1) + atoi(arg2);
    }
    sprintf (output,"%d", value);
    printf ("The output value is %s", output);
```

This code works only if I give expression having multiplication. For example it works only if I give 5*6. This is not working if I give 5+6.

The problem is in the else part. It is not able to tokenize the string input2.

Can't I tokenize two different strings in a single program.

Where am I wrong? Can someone explain me this concept of why strtok is not working for secong string?

Comment: Sure, you can. Your approach seems ok. What exactly does not work?

Comment: But it gives me segmentation fault error. I do not know why? Struggling since yesterday

Comment: It segfaults in which line? Did you compile with option `-g` to have debug info added to the executable? Go for a debugger. For example learn to use GDB.

Comment: Btw: This does not look like C++. You might like to decide which tag to use, as C and C++ are not the same.

Comment: I am running the program on an embedded device on which there is no gdb. So I used to printf statements to know which line it segfaults. It is the first strtok in the else part

Comment: You know that `""` and `" "` aren't the same thing, right?

Comment: I'd test such code on an emulator or on a different platform. If it then works, test it on the embedded device.

Comment: The basic logic looks ok (although there are much better ways to parse expressions), but you have some mistakes. For example you redefine arg1 and arg2 and you have a space in the last strtok. Also I hope your input function knows it only has 20 bytes to play with…

Comment: @JimBalter I know that both are not same. I tried using both just to try with a different thing. Both of them gives me the error

Comment: Is your input certainly null-terminated? If not, you will see that behaviour.

Comment: @Dave I only redefined arg1 and arg2 only because the code was not working and I thought it is better to make arg1 and arg2 local to that particular block. Yes it is null terminated. I have checked it using printfs

Comment: `atoi()`is evil, as is returns `0` on error **and** when being passed `"0"`. Go for `strtol()`.

Comment: Also `atoi()` will run into Undefined Behaviour when being pass in `NULL`. So test the values returned by `strtok()`.

Comment: i would run the code on your development machine (that is: a "real" computer that has the ressources to install debuggers) if it makes problems. really no need for an emulator or the like, it crashes fine on i386 (due to `atoi(NULL)`)

Comment: I probably wouldn't do it like that. You're hard coding dependency on input in your code.

Comment: @KranthiKumar just try printing values of arg1 and arg2.I think umlaeute is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) call will not return `NULL` (unless your input string is either empty or only contains `'*'` characters), so the `else` statement will not be executed for a string like `"5+6"`.

You probably want to use [`strchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) (or similar) to figure out what operation is to be performed, and then get the operands.

Comment: Thank You so much for the answer. I was just expecting that first strtok will return NULL if the input is 5+6. I was wrong. Thank You also for the suggesting me strchr.

Answer (score 2):

the first `strtok` will not return `NULL` for "3+5", but rather a pointer to the token "3+5"
(so the else statement won't get executed).

now the problem is that the *second* call to `strtok` (around line #12 in your code) will return `NULL`, and the subsequent call `atoi(NULL)` will segfault.

Answer (score 1):

case of input "3+5" result of strtok(input1, "*") is "3+5", That else clause is not executed because it should not be NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Second parameter for strtok is an array use like this `strtok (input1, "+*")`. That means that it will tokenize if they get `'*'` or  `'+'`.

Comment: but then you end up with to operands `5` and `6`, but the *operator* is lost and you don't know what to do...

Comment: Then add avariable `int calLen` and add how much you have calculated from `input1` the `if(input1[calLen+] == '+') //do addition work` or `if(input1[calLen+] == '*') //do multiplication work`. Use `calcLen += arg1.Length()` for getting the position of operator.

Comment: @pcbabu thanks for your solution. I feel that you are slightly getting deviated from my question. I do not want different ways of getting the solution. I asked why the second strtok is not working. I want the clear understanding of strtok

Answer (score -1):

I code this like below:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    char ss[100] = "123+321";

    int a = atoi(ss);
    int aLength = (int)floor(log10((double)a))+1;
    int b = atoi(ss+aLength);
    if(ss[aLength] == '+')
        printf("%d + %d = %d\n", a, b, (a+b));
    else
        printf("%d * %d = %d\n", a, b, (a*b));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not in the language requested. Maybe I should add an example in Python...

Comment: I asked it in C not in c++

Comment: user `char ss[100]` instead of `string ss` . use `printf` instead of 'cout'. that is your C.

Comment: `log10((double)a` -- ugh; wrong tool for the wrong job, fails on " 5 + 6 " or "05+06"